# Exponential model (Advent of code 2021 day 6)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

In yesterday's Advent of code puzzle (https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/6), we are asked to model a population of fish, and the model works like this (see link for more infos):

- Each fish is represented by a number
- The number decreases each day
- Once it reaches 0, on the next day, two things will happen: the fish number is reset to 6 (this means it will cycle every 7 days), and a new fish with a value of 8 is created. This means the first time a fish is born, it will take 9 days to generate a new fish.

Basically, a fish has a child every 7 days, and the new fish need 2 more days the first time they have a child.

I've managed to solve it programmatically, but I have yet to find a mathematical formula to solve this problem. To simplify the problem, I'm considering a single fish at the start, with a value of 0, and I'm trying to find a formula that gives the fish population every day, up to 256 days.

For reference, a fish starting at 0 on day 0 will produce a population of 1421 on day 80, and 6 703 087 164 on day 256.

Can anyone help creating this formula ?

EDIT: After Mike's answer, I've implemented the solution in R, if anyone is interested the code is below.

```
library(expm) # Exponents on matrices
options(scipen = 50) # Show all digits in final result
inp <- scan('aoc2021/day6.csv',0L,sep=',',quiet=T) # Read data
V0 <- c(0,table(inp), 0, 0, 0) # Compute frequencies of fish as first state and pad with 0
A <- matrix(0L, nrow = 9, ncol = 9) # Create empty matrix
diag(A[,2:9]) <- A[7,1] <- A[9,1] <- 1L # Fill 1 in matrix

sum((A %^% 256) %*% V0) # Sum of all fish after 256 days
```

The new solution is much faster than the old one (both are really fast).

Time to compute the number of fish after 256 days:

```
expression    median
matrices      7.34µs
programming  99.62µs
```

Comment: Do you know about matrices? There is a nice way of encoding a time-step as a matrix multiplication, and the “state” at each point in time as a vector: the number of fish with timer 0, timer 1, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanding on [Joppy's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/431940/joppy)).

For each $t\in \mathbb N$ and $i\in \{0,\dots,8\}$, let $v_{t,i}$ be the number of fish with level $i$ at time $t$, and let $v_t=(v_{0,t},v_{1,t},\dots,v_{8,t})$. You can show that $v_{t+1}$ is determined from $v_t$ via matrix multiplication. Specifically,
$$
v_{t+1}=Av_t,\qquad A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It follows by induction that that
$$
v_t = A^t v_0,
$$
giving a simple formula for the fish distribution at time $t$. If you like, this implies the number of fish at time $t$ is given by the formula ${\bf 1}^{\top}Av_t$, where ${\bf 1}$ is the column vector with nine ones.

If you further like, you could put this matrix in Jordon form, which should give a formula for the number of fish  at time $t$ in the form $\sum_i p_i(t) (\lambda_i)^t$, where $\{\lambda_i\}_{i\in I}$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$, and $p_i(t)$ are certain polynomials in $t$. However, in this case the eigenvalues are irrational, so this form is not well suited for exact integer computation. The previous formula is excellent for computation, since you can compute $A^t$ with only $O(\log t)$ matrix multiplications using exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I tried to implement the solution with matrices after reading Joppy's comment but didn't managed to do it. With all your explanations it was much easier. The library I used for matrix exponentiation does it in O(log2(k)) which is pretty fast